# Auditing with neo4j: which approach to use?

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I need the auditing feature at the application that uses neo4j, something similar to [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/). I haven't found the existing solution for this so I am curious how to implement my own one.

I am planning to use [lifecycle event](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/#d5e1169) to generate an old version of node and store it to database (relationship are planned to be persistent at the moment, so need to track node changes only).

I would like to know which approach is better:

1. Generate nodes of the custom type and keep information about changes (ID of the user who made the change, date & time of change, ID of node changed and old state of the changed node) into these nodes. For instance, for user changing his name something like this will be generated:

`(:Audit:{userID:"001", timeInMillis:"1471507577436", objectID:"4178a373-d6e0-434f-bc45-cf472c106f1a", oldState:"userID:001, firstName:John, secondName:Doe"})`

2. Keep the old version of the node the same type of node itself, linked to the node itself, adding the revision property with time in milliseconds timestamp there.

Th first approach will be probably slow on large datasets, but it is easier to implement. I would like to know which option is best here.

Answer (score 2):

My answer doesn't address manual approaches, just suggests an existing product that may fulfill your needs.

If you are using or plan to use neo4j enterprise edition, [GraphAware Enterprise](http://graphaware.com/enterprise/) includes several additional modules to enhance neo4j, including an auditing module (others include additional and flexible security and account features and schema enforcement and monitoring).

From their site:

> This extension allows you to see who made changes to your graph, when
>   and what exactly was changed. You can monitor the changes by time
>   range, by user or by specific area of the graph. This feature is great
>   for keeping track of the changes to your graph when working in larger
>   teams. It can also be customised to fit your needs and show exactly
>   the changes you are interested in.

I haven't used this myself, so I can't speak to how flexible or useful it is in practice, you may want to get in touch with GraphAware for more details on usage and capabilities.